# How to find collision detection between sprite and bezier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, box2d-iphone

I usually use box2d for collision detection between two sprites like below code

```
- (void)beginContact:(b2Contact *)contact {

b2Fixture *fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
b2Fixture *fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
b2Fixture *fixtureC = contact->GetFixtureA();

b2Body *bodyA = fixtureA->GetBody();
b2Body *bodyB = fixtureB->GetBody();
b2Body *bodyC = fixtureC->GetBody();
CCSprite *spriteA = (CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
CCSprite *spriteB = (CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData()
LHBezierNode* bez = (LHBezierNode *) bodyC->GetUserData();
if ((spriteB == _enemy && spriteB == _hero) ||
(spriteA == _enemy && spriteA == _hero)) {
NSLog(@"enemy touched");
}
}
```

But I am confused how to detect collision detection between bazier and sprite.any help is appreciated.thanks

This is my bezier

```
LHBezierNode* myBezier = [LH bezierNodeWithUniqueName:@"BezierName"];
```

note : i use level helper for bezier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding tag to brezier, thanks